# Can't fullscreen phaser + webpack + cordova in android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phaser-framework

I using *Phaser-ce 2.7.3*, *Webpack 2.2.0* and *Cordova 6.4.0*
My code

```
import 'pixi'
import 'p2'
import Phaser from 'phaser'

import BootState from './states/Boot'
import MenuState from './states/Menu'
import GameState from './states/Game'
import WinState from './states/Win'

class Game extends Phaser.Game {

constructor () {
   const width = window.innerWidth
   const height = window.innerHeight
   super(width, height, Phaser.CANVAS, 'content', null)
   this.state.add('Boot', BootState, false)
   this.state.add('Menu', MenuState, false)
   this.state.add('Game', GameState, false)
   this.state.add('Win', WinState, false)

   this.state.start('Boot')
 }

}

window.game = new Game()
```

And instade of full size screen get black line in buttom

[image]

Comment: well i don't know the problem but you can check about Phaser.ScaleManager here : http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.ScaleManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix with cordova-custom-config plugin and adding

`<preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:theme" 
value="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />` to `config.xml`